# Javascript scope different depending how you pass callback function

Tags: javascript

```
function DoSomething()
{
     var scope = this;
}
```

Consider the following methods of invoking it:
Option 1:

```
var self= this;
$someElement.change(self.DoSomething);
```

Option 2:

```
var self= this;
$someElement.change(function(){self.DoSomething();});
```

Why is it that the when the change event is triggered, the first line of code results in `scope` being the element that triggered the event, but the second results in a `scope` that is the same as `self` but the second?

Since I don't understand the concept at hand here, it has been difficult for me to Google the correct search term.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Comment: Because a function can be called with _.call_ and _.apply_, where the first argument represent the context ( _this_ ); therefore _this_ is contextual.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

jQuery calls the given function within a context of original element.

**Option 1:**

You have passed `self.DoSomething` as a function.
jQuery will call `self.DoSomething` within a context of `$someElement`:

The following code is executed:

```
var self = this;
self.DoSomething.call($someElement);

function DoSomething()
{
    // this = $someElement
    var scope = this;
}
```

within `DoSomething` `this` is equal to callee - `$someElement`.

**Option 2:**

You have passed anonymous function as a function.
jQuery will call anonymous function within a context of `$someElement`:

```
var self = this; 
function() {
    self.DoSomething();
}.call($someElement);

function() {
    // this = $someElement, as well
    self.DoSomething(); // LOOK! You call self's method. Not within any context
}

function DoSomething()
{
    // default function call, default this is presented
}
```